# Run executable with input and redirect the output to txt file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command

I'm trying to redirect the result of the.exe file into a .txt file, but the command I used in windows cmd

```
test.ext < input.txt > output.txt
```

didn't correctly show what input file input:

```
Enter top, an integer between 3 and 29 (including): Enter side, an integer between 2 and 20 (including): Enter 0 for left-tilt or 1 for right-tilt of the side: 
             ###
            #@#
           #@#
          ###

The number of characters on the perimeter:     10.
The number of characters in the interior:      2.
The number of characters of the parallelogram: 12.
```

In my expectation, the output should be like this:

```
Enter top, an integer between 3 and 29 (including): 3
Enter side, an integer between 2 and 20 (including): 2
Enter 0 for left-tilt or 1 for right-tilt of the side: 0

             ###
            #@#
           #@#
          ###

The number of characters on the perimeter:     10.
The number of characters in the interior:      2.
The number of characters of the parallelogram: 12.
```

Just like what the .exe file shows me when I run it.

Is there any simple way to implement what I want?

Comment: not voting for duplicate because there is no (satisfying) answer: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338287/subprocess-to-completely-emulate-a-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- The behavior comes down to how a given executable chooses to handle (by default) *interactive prompts*, notably with respect to when their responses are instead provided *via stdin* (such as via a `<` redirection or via pipeline input (`|`)) rather than by *what the user types interactively*.
- The upshot is that the only way to get different behavior is to *modify the executable*.

---

**Two aspects** come into play:

- Whether an interactive prompt's *message* is written to *stdout* vs. *directly to the terminal*, and whether to print the message *at all* if stdin is redirected, i.e. if the responses will be read from stdin.
- Whether an prompt's *response* is written to *stdout* vs. either *directly to the terminal* or *not at all* in the event of the response having been provided *via stdin*.

***Ideally*, you'd expect a given executable to choose one of the following combinations *if stdin is redirected***, based on the following design choice:

- **(a)** If (by default) interactive prompts are considered a purely interactive feature that is irrelevant to the application's (stdout) *output*:

  - Print *neither* the prompt message nor the value read from stdin.
- **(b)** If the application wants to produce output that is more like a *transcript* of an interactive session, showing both the prompt messages and responses:

  - Print *both* the prompt message and the value from stdin, to *stdout*.

---

Unfortunately, **your executable uses neither approach** and makes the following combination of choices:

- It writes the prompt message to stdout while *not* printing the (stdin-provided) response
- Since the prompt messages themselves do not having a trailing newline - given that the response should be typed *on the same line* - the absence of also printing the response (which *does* involve a trailing newline (line break)) means that all (consecutive) prompt messages appear on the same line.

***Batch files***, for instance, **exhibit this behavior**, which you can verify with the following sample batch file:

```bash
@echo off

set /P V1="Prompt 1: "
set /P V2="Prompt 2: "
set /P V3="Prompt 3: "

echo Values provided: [%V1%] [%V2%] [%V3%]
```

Invoked as `sample.cmd < input.txt > output.txt` with 3 lines of input in `input.txt` containing `a`, `b`, and `c`, you'd see the following output in `output.txt`:

```bash
Prompt 1: Prompt 2: Prompt 3: Values provided: [a] [b] [c]
```

That is, the prompt messages are concatenated without line breaks, and the responses are missing.

---

***PowerShell's* behavior** is platform-specific, but **a (b) solution is possible either way**:

**Important**: The following only applies to calling PowerShell code from the *outside*, via its *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)), because only then does `Read-Host` read responses from *redirected stdin*. On *Unix*-like platforms, it therefore also applies to a directly executable shell script implemented in PowerShell via a shebang line.

- On ***Unix*-like platforms**, you would get the desired behavior, (b), with regular [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) calls, as shown in the following sample code:

  ```bash
   $values = 
     1..3 | ForEach-Object {
       Read-Host -Prompt "Prompt ${_}"
     }

   "Values provided: $($values.ForEach({ "[$_]" }))"
  ```
- On **Windows**, unfortunately, the prompt message is *printed directly to the console* and therefore *not* captured via a stdout redirection (`>`); the workaround is print the prompt message *separately*, using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) with its `-NoNewLine` switch:

  ```bash
   $values = 
     1..3 | ForEach-Object {
       Write-Host -NoNewLine "Prompt ${_}: "
       Read-Host
     }

   "Values provided: $($values.ForEach({ "[$_]" }))"
  ```

Invoked, say, from `cmd.exe` as  `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File sample.ps1 < input.txt > output.txt` with 3 lines of input in `input.txt` containing `a`, `b`, and `c`, you'd see the following output in `output.txt`:

```bash
Prompt 1: a
Prompt 2: b
Prompt 3: c
Values provided: [a] [b] [c]
```

That is, this amounts to behavior (b): Both the prompt messages and the stdin-provided responses were printed to stdout<sup>[1]</sup> and therefore captured via `>`.

---

**PowerShell also enables an (a) solution**, with additional effort:

```bash
$values = 
  1..3 | ForEach-Object {
    # Print the prompt message only if stdin isn't redirected.
    if (-not [Console]::IsInputRedirected) {
      Write-Host -NoNewline "Prompt ${_}: "
    }
    # Use the [Console]::ReadLine() rather than Read-Host,
    # which *doesn't* echo a stdin-provided response.
    [Console]::ReadLine()
  }

"Values provided: $($values.ForEach({ "[$_]" }))"
```

Using the same sample invocation as above, you now get:

```bash
Values provided: [a] [b] [c]
```

That is, this amounts to behavior (a): Due to the stdin redirection (`<`), neither the prompt messages nor the stdin-provided responses were printed and are therefore *not* part of what `>` captured.

---

Note:

- Given that PowerShell is built on .NET, the implication is that a compiled .NET console application can implement the same behaviors, as the following C# examples show.

**C# implementation of (a)**

```cs
using System;

static class Program {
  public static int Main(string[] args) {

    bool isStdInRedirected = Console.IsInputRedirected;
    int promptCount = 3;
    string[] values = new string[promptCount];

    for (int i = 1; i <= promptCount; ++i)
    {
      Console.Write(String.Format("Prompt {0}: ", i));
      values[i-1] = Console.ReadLine(); 
      if (isStdInRedirected) Console.WriteLine(values[i-1]);
    }

    Console.Write("Values provided:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= promptCount; ++i)
    {
      Console.Write(String.Format(" [{0}]", values[i-1]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    return 0;
  }
}
```

**C# implementation of (b)**

```cs
static class Program {
  public static int Main(string[] args) {

    bool isStdInRedirected = Console.IsInputRedirected;
    int promptCount = 3;
    string[] values = new string[promptCount];

    for (int i = 1; i <= promptCount; ++i)
    {
      if (!isStdInRedirected) Console.Write(String.Format("Prompt {0}: ", i));
      values[i-1] = Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    Console.Write("Values provided:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= promptCount; ++i)
    {
      Console.Write(String.Format(" [{0}]", values[i-1]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    return 0;
  }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Perhaps surprisingly, `Write-Host` too prints to stdout, even though PowerShell-*internally* it is designed to *bypass* PowerShell's analogous *success* [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).

In fact - unfortunately - by default *all* of PowerShell's (six!) output streams are mapped to the stdout stream seen by outside callers - see [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for replying. Does this method only suit PowerShell scripts? If using an .exe file, how do I apply this method?

Comment: @抹茶抹茶: I've added C# implementations of both (a) and (b) to the answer. It should be possible to do the same in non-.NET languages.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect input.txt into console/cmd directly instead of using stdin?

Comment: @抹茶抹茶: I don't understand the question. Redirections apply to the standard streams of processes. CLIs expect input either via arguments or via stdin.

Comment: Sorry for that; now I understand what you do, but I am not familiar with C#. Is it possible to implement this code in Python or C/C++?